# Random numbers every .Next() call [ Multiple .Next() in method]

Tags: c#

I have a problem with random number generating in C#

I have tried all the solutions that I've found. Most we're only using the same random object every time which works only each object, not each property.

So I am using this as code for the random numbers:

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
            lock (syncLock)
            { // synchronize
                return random.Next(min, max);
            }
}
```

Now I want to call `.Next()` multiple times in the same method, to generate a random object:

```
public void StartDuiven()
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
   {
      var d = new Duif();
      d.Naam = /*NameGenerator.GenRandomFirstName() +" "+ NameGenerator.GenRandomLastName()*/ "Jantje";
      d.GeboorteDatum = DateTime.Now;
      d.Snelheid = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Vliegtechniek = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Vormpeil = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Conditie = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Aerodynamica = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Intelligentie = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Libido = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Nachtvliegen = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Navigatie = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Ervaring = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 4);
      d.Transfer = false;

      int g = Genrator.RandomNumber(0, 2); // Edited

      if (g == 0)
         d.Geslacht = false;
      else
         d.Geslacht = true;

      AddDuif(d);
   }
}
```

Every new object I get a different number, but not every time I call .`Next()` method.

So all the values of the properties become the same for 1 object.

How could I fix this? Why don't I get a new value on each `.Next()` call?

Thank you

Bye!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Random.Next(0, 1)` will always return `0`.  The max value is exclusive.

Comment: Alright i'll make that 0,2 then. Any idea on the problem that every .Next() call returns the same?

Comment: +1 to answer... @JonasBohez - random numbers are random, why do you expect them to be different? Your restriction of "next number must not repeat previous" makes for very special distribution, not one provided by regular Random object.

Comment: Nvm on the last question, that was my own fault somewhere else :/ Thanks for the 0,2 edit though

Answer (score 2):

Due to pigeonhole principle it is hard :) to get 5 distinct integer value in range of [0-4).

Since numbers are random you should expect that there will be some number of cases when all values will be the same.

(in addition to bug identified by @IngisKahn with usage of `Random.Next(0,1)`)

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
return (random.Next() % (max - min)) + min
```

Comment: It works with this also thanks! Though, I apolagize, i kept giving the same value somewhere. 

Sorry for wasting anyones time with this :( !